# ESXI 5.0.0 guests locking up

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-esxi

I have an ESXI 5.0.0 running four Windows Server 2008 R2 guests. They are named: APP, EXCH, DC, RDS.

Just as of last night, one guest (DC) locked up. We reset the guest this morning after noticing the issue and it came up properly. However, we noticed after resetting that guest, APP and EXCH locked up in the same manner. Resetting them brought them up properly, but locked up DC.

All of these guests are provisioned with thick storage provisioning and reserved RAM.

I have checked out the ESXI events and see nothing. I have checked out esxtop and similarly see nothing abnormal. Once locked up the VMs use next to no resources.

Once locked up, opening the console for a VM shows the Windows login screen, but the mouse can't be moved and no keys can be pressed.

Can anyone provide some assistance on where I can start troubleshooting this? I run a few ESXI installations but have not seen an issue like this.

Thanks kindly

Comment: Are you using a SAN for your datastore or are you hosting all the VMs locally on one host?  Can you also provide information about resource usage, before and during these incidents?  Do you have any services that require one server to be up before another?

Comment: Do you have the VMware guest tools running inside of any of your guest VM's?